# Content not visible on homepage

Tags: wordpress

I have problem with wordpress, I don't know why, but only on german version central content not showing (only header and footer visible), in administration, containers and content are visible, but on page not displaying, on other language works fine.

In inspect element not visible also.

I don't have any idea why!

Comment: Which translation plugin you are using?

Comment: Check your error_log file and enable debug mode

Answer (score 0):

It may possible that your content is not translated into German version.

Comment: Worked before this!

Comment: using any translation plugins ?